# Navigating the Facebook App Development Process with Advanced Permission Needs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently developing a Facebook app that primarily requires advanced permissions to function properly. However, I'm facing a catch-22 situation: I need these advanced permissions to build and test my app, but to get these permissions, I need to have a functioning app ready for Facebook's review.

Has anyone experienced a similar situation, and how did you navigate this? Specifically, I'm looking for advice on:

Strategies for developing an app when core functionalities depend on advanced permissions.
Best practices for demonstrating the need for advanced permissions to Facebook reviewers, especially when the app is still in development.
Tips on using tokens from the Graph API Explorer effectively for building and showcasing app features during the development phase.
Any insights, tips, or personal experiences would be greatly appreciated!

I currently haven't tried a method, I am new to this development.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-modes

Comment: Hmm I am in development mode, but I need access to advanced permissions, which I can't get without submitting the app for review, but I can't submit app for review without building the app as the core functions of the app are dependent on the advanced permissions. Hence the catch 22.

Comment: I am not sure where exactly the problem is supposed to be here, can you give an example of a permission you are having trouble with? According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels#changing-access-levels app admins should be able to switch permissions back to Standard access, in which case testing should be no problem.